# How can I solve this strange error with SSH Task in Azure Pipeline

Tags: ssh, azure-devops

I'm trying to use the SSH deploy task in Azure devops, but I'm struggling to get it to work.

### Steps:

1. I generated a ssh-key
2. The key is added to the server
3. (optional) tested key locally (works)
4. Created a Service connection in Azure Devops (with the private key data and the passfrase in the password field)
5. Allow the correct pipeline in Service connection security
6. Added the [SSH task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/ssh?view=azure-devops) to the release pipeline.
7. Added an inline script.

### Connection succeeds

It seems to connect but doesn't execute the commands. I've checked the `/var/log/auth.log` file on the server and that does show a successfull connection. The authentication log on the remote server does show a successfull authentication from devops, the connects lasts exactly the value set for the timeout.

### Wrong order, logging shows commands then connected

In the logging it shows my second (`docker-compose pull`) and third command (`docker-compose up -d`) but not the first command. And the commands are shown **before** the trying to connect line. The first command isn't shown at all.

Did I make a mistake or is their something else going on?

Here is the logging of the task

```
2020-02-12T15:05:23.7258315Z ##[section]Starting: Run SSH
2020-02-12T15:05:23.8777631Z ==============================================================================
2020-02-12T15:05:23.8778469Z Task         : SSH
2020-02-12T15:05:23.8778560Z Description  : Run shell commands or a script on a remote machine using SSH
2020-02-12T15:05:23.8778657Z Version      : 0.151.1
2020-02-12T15:05:23.8778735Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2020-02-12T15:05:23.8778839Z Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/ssh
2020-02-12T15:05:23.8778953Z ==============================================================================
2020-02-12T15:05:24.5860676Z docker-compose pull
2020-02-12T15:05:24.5860824Z docker-compose up -d
2020-02-12T15:05:24.5861194Z Trying to establish an SSH connection to ***@my-server.domain.com:22
2020-02-12T15:05:25.4787782Z (node:4364) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
2020-02-12T15:05:25.4789160Z (node:4364) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
2020-02-12T15:05:25.4791265Z (node:4364) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
2020-02-12T15:05:25.4791477Z (node:4364) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
2020-02-12T15:05:25.4792286Z (node:4364) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
2020-02-12T15:05:25.4792439Z (node:4364) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
2020-02-12T15:05:25.4792552Z (node:4364) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
2020-02-12T15:05:25.4792648Z (node:4364) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
2020-02-12T15:05:25.4792757Z (node:4364) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
2020-02-12T15:05:25.4792851Z (node:4364) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
2020-02-12T15:05:25.4792960Z (node:4364) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
2020-02-12T15:05:25.4793055Z (node:4364) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
2020-02-12T15:05:25.7447781Z Successfully connected.
2020-02-12T15:05:25.7564295Z ##[error]Unhandled: Cannot parse privateKey: Unsupported key format
2020-02-12T15:09:23.7874932Z ##[error]The task has timed out.
2020-02-12T15:09:23.7877908Z ##[section]Finishing: Run SSH
```

### Task YAML

```
- task: SSH@0
  displayName: 'Run remote docker-compose commands'
  inputs:
    sshEndpoint: 'Endpoint name redacted'
    runOptions: inline
    inline: |
     cd ~/correct-folder/
     docker-compose pull
     docker-compose up -d
  timeoutInMinutes: 4
```

I've tried both Windows and Ubuntu hosted agents.

### Unrelated issues that show same error:

- https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/12147
- [Node Cipheriv Warning in Azure DevOps Extension - Release Task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55091341/node-cipheriv-warning-in-azure-devops-extension-release-task)
- Issue on with node https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/16746

### Same issue, with explaination

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55093077/639153

It seems like the Task library is calling the wrong node function, as "solved" in march '19.

Answer (score 0):

I know your step 7 says you added an Inline script, but any chance that you are using the  run shell command option and not the `Inline` script option? A hunch from your description about the order of operations being off.

> NOTE: Each command runs in a separate process. If you want to run a series of commands that are interdependent (for example, changing the current folder before executing a command) use the Inline Script option instead.

From the [docs on the task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/ssh?view=azure-devops)

Comment: That could be the issue, so I just double checked and added the yaml of the task to the original question.

Comment: @Stephan Based on your edit you are using the Inline script option so that should be good. Based on this issue on [github](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/11439) what if you turn off the new service connection preview feature and try to regenerate the Service Connection?

Comment: your suggestion doesn't work. The result is the same. It already did connect to the server, but it connects after the commands are already in the log. So I think it might be a bug in the task anyway.

Answer (score -1):

What about using private agent? Just try to run a simple command such like `ipconfig` and check the result.

Besides, according to the error message `Unhandled: Cannot parse privateKey: Unsupported key format` this seems a privateKey format issue.

So, please try to convert the existing key using ssh-keygen utility to the old PEM format and try it again to check if that works.

`ssh-keygen -p -m PEM -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa`

Comment: As stated in the original question, it does connect successfully, but it doesn't execute the commands on the server. I already tried to change the commands to an echo, but that didn't work either.

Comment: The other key format results in the same error and also listing the commands in the logging before the error that it cannot connect. So `Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr` ten times then my 2nd and 3th command then connecting.....